# Evaluating the sum $\sum_{k=1}^\infty (-1)^k / k^2$ via a contour integral

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, contour-integration

I'm evaluating the sum:

\begin{align*}
\sum_{k=1}^\infty (-1)^k \frac{1}{k^2}
\end{align*}

I expressed the sum via a complex contour integration. But I'm not getting out the right answer.

My method: It employs the fact that the function

\begin{align*}
\dfrac{1}{\tan \pi z}
\end{align*}

has simple poles at all integers $n$. This allows us to write

\begin{align*}
\sum_{k=1}^\infty (-1)^k \frac{1}{k^2} = \frac{1}{2 i} \oint_C e^{i \pi z} \dfrac{1}{z^2 \tan \pi z} dz
\end{align*}

where the contour $C$ is defined in fig (a).

[image]

We have

\begin{align*}
\sum_{k=1}^\infty (-1)^k \frac{1}{k^2} & = \frac{1}{2} \sum_{k=1}^\infty (-1)^k \frac{1}{k^2} + \frac{1}{2} \sum_{k=-1}^{-\infty} (-1)^k\frac{1}{k^2}
= \frac{1}{4 i} \oint_{C+C'} e^{i \pi z} \dfrac{1}{z^2 \tan \pi z} dz
\end{align*}

where the contour $C'$ is defined in fig (a). We complete the path of integration along semicircles at infinity (see fig (b)) since the integrand vanishes there. Since the resulting enclosed area contains no singularities except at $z=0$, we can shrink this contour down to an infinitesimal circle $C_0$ around the origin (see fig (c)). So that

\begin{align}
\sum_{k=1}^\infty (-1)^k \frac{1}{k^2} = \frac{1}{4 i} \oint_{C_0} e^{i \pi z} \dfrac{1}{z^2 \tan \pi z} dz
\end{align}

Expanding the integrand around $z=0$, we get

\begin{align}
e^{i\pi z} \dfrac{1}{z^2 \tan \pi z} = (1 + i \pi z - \frac{1}{2!} \pi^2 z^2 + \cdots ) \dfrac{1}{z^2 (\pi z + \frac{1}{3} \pi^3 z^3 + \cdots)}
\end{align}
\begin{align}
= (1 + i \pi z - \frac{1}{2!} \pi^2 z^2 + \cdots ) \dfrac{1}{z^3 \pi (1 + \frac{1}{3} \pi^2 z^2 + \cdots)}
\end{align}
\begin{align}
= \cdots + (1 - \frac{1}{2!} \pi^2 z^2 + \cdots ) \dfrac{1}{z^3 \pi} (1 - \frac{1}{3} \pi^2 z^2 + \cdots)
\end{align}
\begin{align}
= \cdots - \dfrac{5\pi}{6} \frac{1}{z} + \cdots
\end{align}

So that

\begin{align*}
\sum_{k=1}^\infty (-1)^k \frac{1}{k^2} = \frac{1}{4 i} \oint_{
C_0} e^{i\pi z} \dfrac{1}{z^2 \tan \pi z} dz
= \frac{1}{4 i} (-2 \pi i) (-\dfrac{5\pi}{6})
= \frac{5 \pi^2}{12}
\end{align*}

Which is the wrong answer, it should be $- \pi^2 /12$. What have I done wrong?

Comment: It doesn't answer your question, but I think that to get $\sum (-1)^n f(n)$ is it easier to integrate $\pi \csc \pi z f(z) $ round a large square contour with vertices at $(N+\frac12)(\pm1\pm i)$. As $N\to\infty$ the integral vanishes if $f$ is suitably small for large $z$.

Comment: @Dave77 I'm trying to refresh my memory on how the contour works. I understand how the summands come from the residues of the integrand at $z=\pm n$ where $1\leq n\in\mathbb{Z}$. However, if the contour doesn't include those integers (as indicated in the figure) how can they possibly be included in the sum of residues? Could you clarify what I'm missing here, I can't seem to see it. On a different note (observation), it's also interesting to see that the single residue at $z=0$ somehow holds all the information about the sum of the other residues !

Comment: @pathfinder. You asked: "However, if the contour doesn't include those integers (as indicated in the figure". So, a closed contour from $i h + N+1/2$ to $i h + 1/2$ to $-i h + 1/2$ to $-i h + N+1/2$ and back to $i h + N+1/2$ is a closed contour containing the first $N$ positive integers. However, in the limit $N \rightarrow \infty$ the contribution to the integral from integrating from $-i h + N+1/2$ to $i h + N+1/2$ vanishes, and as such does not need to be included. This is why the contour $C$ indicated in fig (a) doesn't have to be closed and surround the integers $1 \leq n$.

Answer (score 7):

The issue is that the integral does not vanish along the bottom semicircle as its radius goes to infinity.

This is because the magnitude of $e^{i \pi z}$ grows exponentially as $\Im(z) \to -\infty$.

But notice that $\pi \csc(\pi z)$ also has simple poles at the integers with residue $$\operatorname{Res}\left[\frac{\pi }{\sin (\pi z)}, k \right] = \lim_{z \to k}\frac{\pi}{\pi \cos (\pi z)} = \frac{1}{\cos(\pi k)} = (-1)^{k}.$$

In addition to being periodic in the real direction, the function $\pi \csc(\pi z)$ tends to zero as $\Im(z) \to \pm \infty$.

Therefore, if we replace $\pi e^{i \pi z}\cot(\pi z)$ with $\pi \csc(\pi z)$, the integral will vanish along both semicircles.